# React Native Axios is sending entire object and not just the value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asp.net-core, axios, expo

This is driving me insane. I am only trying to post a date to my api and I am getting a json error of "The JSON value could not be converted to System.DateTime."

The reason why is axios or React Native is not sending the value of my object. It is sending the key and value which can't be parsed by my api.

here is my date

`date = new Date().toISOstring()` which outputs `"2024-01-07T02:23:08.805Z"`

here is what console log says my date is which is not what I expect. I expect just the value and not the key

```
{"date": "2024-01-07T02:23:08.805Z"}
```

Here is my api endpoint

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetAssignmentsByDate([FromBody] DateTime date)
```

Here is the request

```
await ApiManager("Assignments/GetAssignmentsByDate" ,{
         method: 'POST',
         headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
         },      
         data: date
        })
        .then(res => {            
            return res})
        .catch(err => handleErrorResponse(err));
```

Here is the log of that request

```
Object {
  "adapter": Array [
    "xhr",
    "http",
  ],
  "baseURL": "https://myendpoint/api/",
  **"data": Object {
    "date": "2024-01-07T02:23:08.805Z",
  },**
  "env": Object {
    "Blob": [Function Blob],
    "FormData": [Function FormData],
  },
  "headers": Object {
    "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  "maxBodyLength": -1,
  "maxContentLength": -1,
  "method": "post",
  "responseType": "json",
  "timeout": 0,
  "transformRequest": Array [
    [Function transformRequest],
  ],
  "transformResponse": Array [
    [Function transformResponse],
  ],
  "transitional": Object {
    "clarifyTimeoutError": false,
    "forcedJSONParsing": true,
    "silentJSONParsing": true,
  },
  "url": "Assignments/GetAssignmentsByDate",
  "validateStatus": [Function validateStatus],
  "withCredentials": true,
  "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
  "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
}
```

If you notice the

```
**"data": Object {
        "date": "2024-01-07T02:23:08.805Z",
      },**
```

Is sending this entire object.

If I exchange `data:date` in the request to
`data: '2024-01-07T02:23:08.805Z'` explicitly then it works as expected

so can someone please explain to me what is happening behind the scenes here with React Native and Axios?

Comment: You have to put it in an object with that property

Comment: Have you tried data: { date: date } ?

Comment: Just before your call to `await ApiManager(.....)` try adding `console.log("typeof date is:", typeof date);` and see what you get.  BTW: what is `ApiManager` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use your object as below

```
const [date, setDate] = useState("");
```

Then pass in the date object and make sure it is sent without any {} as I assume that is what you are doing based on the way the object looks {}

```
"data": Object {
        "date": "2024-01-07T02:23:08.805Z",
      }
```

Then it should work

```
export const SendtheDate = async date =>{ 
    console.log(date)    
}
```